# Hibernate LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to get the versions field within my MachineGroup Entity that is ManyToMany relationship. I am trying to fetch it in a custom serializer using ObjectMapper but for some reason I always get the LazyInitializationException - org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.altair.autoTester.entities.machinegroup.MachineGroup.versions, could not initialize proxy - no Session.

MachineGroup

```
@Entity
@Table(name="machine_groups")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MachineGroup {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "machine_groups_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "machine_groups_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 2)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "machine_groups_to_versions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "machine_group_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "version_id"))
    @JsonManagedReference(value="machineGroups-versions")
    private Set<Version> versions = new HashSet<>();
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "machine_groups_to_tr_types",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "machine_group_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tr_type_id"))
    private Set<TrType> trTypes = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Version.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="versions")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Version {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "versions_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "versions_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "creation_time")
    private Date creationTime;
    @Column(name = "exe_file")
    @Lob
    private Blob exeFile;
    @JsonBackReference(value="machineGroups-versions")
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "versions", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Set<MachineGroup> machineGroups = new HashSet<>();

    public Version(){};

    public Version(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

MachineGroupSerializer.java

```
public class MachineGroupSerializer extends StdSerializer<MachineGroup> {

    public MachineGroupSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public MachineGroupSerializer(Class<MachineGroup> t) {
        super(t);
    }

@Transactional
    @Override
    public void serialize(MachineGroup machineGroup,
                          JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {

        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("id",machineGroup.getId());
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("versions", machineGroup.getVersions().stream().map(Version::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
      jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("trTypes", machineGroup.getTrTypes().stream().map(TrType::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet()));

        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

TrTypes.java

```
@Table(name = "tr_types", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "tr_types_type_name_uindex", columnList = "type_name", unique = true)
})
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TrType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "type_name", nullable = false)
    private String typeName;
}
```

I put the JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference so I won't have infinite loop calling one another, not sure if it's causing any issues.

Calling the getTrTypes() function works but has the EAGER fetchType which I do not want to add to the versions collection.

What can cause this lazy exception to occur and how can I prevent it?

Also the function calling the serialzier within my MachineGroupService has the @Transactional annotation, I saw something that is related to the hibernate session that might be close at the serializer level.

Comment: The `@Transactional` in the serializer doesn't do anything, since the serializer is not a managed bean.

Comment: I assume you are persisting these entities in your service layer. Post that serialization is ok.

also can you try adding CascadeType.PERSIST

bonus,please override `hashcode,equals and tostring(add only basic fields not collections)` manually. If you are missing `equals` and `hascode`, set contract is not followed

Comment: @swapyonubuntu Where should I add these?

Comment: In machinegroup, add to 
```@ManyToMany(cascade ={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST} )
private Set<Version> versions
```
ideally you should override hashcode,equals and tostring for all entities
but for starters add equals, hascode and tostring to both versions and machine group entities. Add no args constructor as well if not present on any entity.

Comment: I made the changes but still same issue